# In C programming: Solving a PDE in two spatial dimensions numerically without using three loops

Tags: c, performance, loops, numerical, pde

I'm trying to write a program in C to solve a PDE in 2 spatial dimentions numerically: W(x,p,t). The acctual equasion involves too many signs that I don't know how to write here, so forgive me for not providing it, but it is fairly irrelevant anyways.

To solve the equation, from what I know - I need three loops:

```
For (t=0;t<t_max;t+=1) 
 For (x=0;x<x_max;x+=1) 
  For (p=0;p<p_max;p+=1) 
   ( The numerical form of the equation, using a 2D array - W[x_max][p_max] )
```

This works fine for one dimension. - but problem is : in the above case the program simply runs in a million years! - I am seriously afraid I might live only to 120 - so I'll never see it complete!

What are methods to solve such equations without three nested loops?
Are there any other techniques to spped up my calculation (e.g. by parallelization)?
What is a good resource to learn more about solving PDEs?

Comment: What kind of PDE is this, what method are you using to solve it?

Comment: BTW - I use the simple Euler method for writing the Numerical form of the PDE, no "fancy" stuff.....

Comment: it goes something like this: dW/dt=-x*p*W+Dd^2/dp^2 W-d/dp F(p)*W

Comment: What is t_max, x_max and p_max? how large are these variables? What are you interested in? Is it the value in a specific point or a specific area?

Comment: The Euler method: W(n+1,j)=x*p*W(n,j)+D*Delta_t*(W(n,j+1)-2W(n,j)+W(n,j-1))/(Delta_p)^2-(d/dpF(p))*W(n,j)-F(p)*(W(n,j+1)-W(n,j-1))/(2*Delta_p)

Comment: t_max=500=x_max=p_max (REAL LONG...!), they just mark a random large limit for the assesment of the function, if I could - I would have taken them as large as possible. I am interested in getting a matrix of all the values of W(x,p,t) with respect to (x,p) paires , at time t_max. The solution of the PDE which I could later on plot or further analyse.  THX for your help!

Comment: You have to lower your expectations. PDE is one of the hardest problems in mathematical computing. Don't expect it to be fast or easy. Even the sofisticated methods such as the finite element method are still slow. If you really need the whole matrix, then I'm afraid there's little potential for optimization. Which operating system do you use (this is slightly relevant for the choice of parallelization)?

Comment: Mmm, I use Linux - Ubuntu 12_04. The problem is - the need for the three loops, any way to go around that? If I was interested only in integrating the solution afterwards over 'p', and remain with g(x,t)? (Andrea Brinck, did u have any idea too?)

Comment: If you want a boost in performance you'll have to switch to a more sophisticated way of solving it. I would suggest looking into the finite element method. Any optimization you do to the current solution will at best give you and order of magnitude improvement in performance which from your description would still be too slow.

Comment: Try the lazy parallelization with omp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Sample_programs to parallelize the loop for p. You cannot expect great impact, but without learning some fancy techniques it's the only way of improving a bit.

Comment: O.K, thanks guys. This was actually helpful indeed, (and very quick btw!). I'll into these two things now, at least I have a direction. I'll post if it works. The acctual reason for posting this thread was to learn about these fancier methods, if any more ideas - I'll be happy to hear. Cheers :-)

Comment: Stephan, in-order to parallelize the loop on 'p', all I need to do is to add to my code: #include <omp.h> and inside the loop on 'x': {#pragma omp parallel for for(...); }, is that right?

Comment: I think that doesn't work - because of the dependance of W(x,p,t) both on naboring 'x' locations, and 'p' location - meaning: I don't believe these can be calculated in parallel.....